# Changing color of image with SVG source with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the color of the X logo on hover. The logo is added to html as an image with the csv in src. I've tried to do it as a mask like suggested in another thread, but my logo disappears.

```
#xLogo {
    width: 18px;
    margin-right: .25rem;
}

a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #282624;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
    color: #FD5A3B;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover > #xLogo,
a:focus > #xLogo,
a:active > #xLogo {
    background-color: #FD5A3B;
    -webkit-mask: url(../img/X_logo.svg) no-repeat center;
    mask: url(../img/X_logo.svg) no-repeat center;
}
```

Here is my link on default:
[image]

And here it is on hover:
[image]

How to make it happen?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` property.

```
a:hover > #xLogo,
a:focus > #xLogo,
a:active > #xLogo {
    filter: invert(21%) sepia(100%) saturate(7414%) hue-rotate(359deg) brightness(94%) contrast(117%);
}
```

Comment: You can use [CSS filter Generator](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp) to do it for any other color.